# Can't load D3 graph with API data

Tags: javascript, json, api, d3.js

I would like to generate my D3 donut chart with the data given by the API. The 'console.log(json)' works : the data is shown in the console, but I can't get it to work with the D3 donut chart.

I get the following error: `'(anonymous function)' line 84` and `'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'`.

Here is the code:

```
(function() {  

var app = angular.module('exampleName', []);
var json

app.controller('apiController', function(){

  var request_data = {
      url: 'oath.php',
      method: 'GET',
      data: {
        term: 'beer',
        site: 'http://api.website.com/'
      } 
  };

  $.ajax({
      url: request_data.url,
      type: request_data.method,
      data: request_data.data,
      dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {

        setTimeout(function() {
             }, 600); 
             json = data; 
             console.log(json);
             var body = d3.select("body");
        var div = body.append("div")
            .attr("id","chart")
            .attr("class","chart")
             var width = 260,
            height = 260;

        var outerRadius = height / 2 - 10,
            innerRadius = outerRadius / 2,
            cornerRadius = 10;
            colors = d3.scale.category20c(); 

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .padAngle(.02)
            .value(function(d) {  
                return d.uploads.count_download.value;
            })

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .padRadius(outerRadius)
            .innerRadius(innerRadius);

        var infoHover = d3.select('#chart').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('padding', '0 25px')
            .style('opacity', 0)

        function arcTween(outerRadius, delay) {
          return function() {
            d3.select(this).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function(d) {
             var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
             return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
            });
          };
        }

        var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .data(data)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")") 
            .selectAll('path').data(pie(data)) 
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                  return colors(i); 
              })
            .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
            .attr('d', arc) 

        .on("touchstart", function(d) {

            infoHover.transition()
                .style('opacity', .9)
                .style('left', '85px')
                .style('top', '120px')

              infoHover.html(d.uploads.count_download.value + '%')

              d3.selectAll("path")
                  .transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .style("opacity", .18)

              d3.select(this)
                  .transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .style('opacity', 1)
                  .style('cursor', 'pointer')   
                  .attr("path", arcTween(outerRadius, 0).call(this)) 

          })

          .on("touchend", function(d) {

              d3.selectAll("path")
                  .transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .style("opacity", 1)

              d3.select(this)
                .style('opacity', .18)
                .attr("path", arcTween(outerRadius - 20,150).call(this)) 
          });  

      }).fail(function(data) {
              console.log("Ajax fail");
        });

    });

}).call(this);
```

***Edit** - The response looks like this:

```
{
"generated_at": "Thu, 18 Sep 2014 18:29:49 GMT",
"uploads": [
    {
    "uploader_id": "6",
    "count_download": 2.0
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at your code snippet, line 84 is a blank line, what line causes the error?  Also, shouldn't `var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").data(data)` be `var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").data(pie(data))`?

Comment: Indeed, in this code snippet it is line 70.`.data(pie(data))` also gives the error '(anonymous function)'.